# How to generate a steady 37kHz GPIO trigger from inside linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, kernel-module, gpio

I have a micro controller taking care of infrared TX-carrier wave generation currently, but I started wondering if I could dispose of it, and do this work in linux side - thus bringing the cost of my embedded system down.

I'm running on a Freescale i.mx233 (454MHz ARM9), and if I access registry directly through `/dev/mem`, I can achieve quite steady 5MHz triggering to a GPIO pin.

Since I need 37kHz, I started looking ways of slowing it down, but it seems that at least `nanowait()` is way too rough for this purpose. 
I found one solution of calling rand() in a for loop, and I seem to be able to generate 38,4kHz signal quite well, However there is some unacceptable jitter from time to time according to oscilloscope. (I understand that this is quite a bit waste of resources, but when the TX needs to be done, the system has no other tasks really)

My questions:
Freescales kernel code (3.8 branch) doesn't have CONFIG_PREEMPT_RT patches, so that is one thing maybe I should look into, but before that:

- Could I achieve more accurate performance, by writing a kernel module to drive the GPIO from inside the kernel ? I do need to read up on some data from user space (data to be sent), but other than that, I only need to trigger the led on specified frequency at the end of the GPIO, so the driver should be pretty simple.
- Can I force the priority of my driver, so that other tasks don't interrupt this gpio triggering ? (data sending takes currently roughly 400ms, and it's done very seldom)
- Is there some better way to create an interrupt say every 37kHz, so that I don't stall the system by SW ?

Micro controller is perfect for this kind of tasks, but it would be nice to avoid this cost overhead if possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The i.MX23 PWM in "Multi-Chip Attachment Mode" is designed exactly for this requirement.

Use one of the PWM's in "Multi-Chip Attachment Mode", for example, assuming you are using a 24Mhz clock, with

1. MATT=1 (Enable multi-chip attachment mode)
2. MATT_SEL=1 (User 24Mhz clock)
3. CDIV=0x2 (or DIV_4, i.e. divide by 4)
4. INACTIVE_STATE=0x2 or 0x3
5. ACTIVE_STATE=0x3 or 0x2
6. PERIOD=175 (i.e 176-1)

If you use a 32Mhz clock you will need other CDIV and PERIOD parameters to get to 34Khz.

See the "i.MX23 Applications Processor Reference Manual" for example code. If I am not mistaken the driver code is in `arch/arm/plat-mxc/pwm.c` but it doesn't seem to support the MATT mode. You will probably have to extend the code yourself.

Regarding the implementation -

The above answer relates to the CPU only. In practice, the ability to implement the idea depends on the board design. The board would need a header (pins for external connection) that connects to a GPIO pin that can be connected via the pinmux to one of the PWMs. I would assume that most reference designs would have at least one PWM configurable GPIO exposed through a header. The the question is if there is only one and if you are already using it for some other control purpose.

After determining that there is a header with a free PWM configurable GPIO, you need to configure the pin mux and activate the PWM. There are instructions for this in the processor reference manual noted above. Most systems do this configuration in the boot loader `board_init()` (assuming U-boot), although it can probably be done in userspace also with some `mmap` trickery after Linux boots.

Finally you would need to write a driver based on the interface to the PWM module in `platform-mxc_pwm.c`.

If you are using the i.MX23 EVK 10.05 you might be able to modify the LED PWM driver since it is already configured at the level of the bootloader and kernel and connect your device to the LED output instead of the LED. (You will need a hardware technician to help you with this.) Make sure you config the kernel with the CONFIG_LEDS_MXS.

The above comments regarding implementation are somewhat speculative since I don't know the EVK. Perhaps someone who knows it can improve on this.

---

### Update September 21, 2013

Another way to generate a 37kHz signal with the i.MX23 or with any SoC with a similar ARM CPU core is to use an unused on-chip timer to generate a FIQ interrupt at the required frequency and write a FIQ interrupt handler to toggle a GPIO pin. Maxime Ripard posted a [complete example](http://free-electrons.com/blog/fiq-handlers-in-the-arm-linux-kernel/) of this method using the i.MX28 SoC on his Free Electrons blog on April 30 this year. To use this method you will need both an unused timer and not be using the FIQ interrupt for another purpose such as one of the SPI, camera, or brownout-detection drivers that use the ARM FIQ. You will also need to write the ISR in ARM assembler.

Comment: Jonathan, this looks very interesting indeed. But, I'm really confused as to how to use this.. would you have any recommendation for me, on how to start testing ?
In Freescales 3.8 kernel source, there seems to exist `/arch/arm/mach-imx/devices/platform-mxc_pwm.c` - but I don't really have any clue how I should start with this..
It seems that one can define a pwm device in dtb ? Is this something I should do ? How do I write userland (or kernel driver) to take advantage of this ?

Sorry for multitude of questions - this really is totally new are to me this kernel programming

Comment: @julumme: Did my best to provide hints. Now you need to find someone who knows your board. I wouldn't think that you would need to touch anything in the DTB.

Comment: Jonathan, I really appreciate for this advice. The 24kHz clock could really be perfect for the job.. if only I could understand how to harness it for my use..

Comment: thanks for setting me on the right path, I have now figured out how to work with PWM, and I have a steady signal for ISR use!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get a 37 kHz signal would be to find some serial/audio/PWM output that can generate it in hardware.

It might be possible to raise the priority of your userspace process, but this won't help against interrupts or high-priority kernel tasks.
An RT kernel would allow you to get priority over more kernel tasks, but wouldn't help against all interrupts.
I don't know if you will be able to get the maximum latency below 37 kHz (27 µs); I think it's unlikely.

Doing this in the kernel would help because you could disable interrupt handling.
However, disabling interrupts for as long as 400 ms is frowned upon.

Comment: CL, this indeed seems to be a good way of going about it - do you happen to have more experience, on how this should be attempted ? This is my first time using linux for embedded design, and frankly I have no idea how can I implement this kind of PWM timer..